# RemoteMediaPlayer seek successful but don't actually seek

Tags: android, chromecast

I have a small issue that i hope someone can help me with.
Today, i noticed that my music app can't seek in the media being played on a ChromeCast device. The seek-request returns successful, but it don't actually seek.

I simply call:

```
public void seek(long position) { //position is in milliseconds 
    if (mListener != null)
        mListener.onSeekStatusChange(true);
    Log.e(TAG, "Seeking to: " + position + " - position: " + mMediaPlayer.getApproximateStreamPosition());
    if (mApiClient != null && mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.seek(mApiClient, position, RemoteMediaPlayer.RESUME_STATE_UNCHANGED).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<MediaChannelResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(MediaChannelResult result) {
                        Status status = result.getStatus();
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            if (mListener != null)
                                mListener.onSeekStatusChange(false);
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to seek: " + status.getStatusCode());
                        }
                    }

                });
    }
}
```

For example, I'll get "Seeking to: 103018 - position: 35709" in the logcat, and if i check the value of status.isSuccess() it will return true.

Chromecast console will give me something like this:

```
[536.007s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"currentTime\":165.395,\"type\":\"SEEK\",\"requestId\":17,\"mediaSessionId\":3}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"3:com.app.groovemobile-49"} cast_receiver.js:18
[536.011s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
[536.017s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received cast_receiver.js:18
[536.021s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager seek event cast_receiver.js:18
[536.030s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onSeek: {"currentTime":165.395,"requestId":17,"mediaSessionId":3} cast_receiver.js:18
[536.034s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message cast_receiver.js:18
[536.040s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":3,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"BUFFERING\",\"currentTime\":99.691977,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false}}],\"requestId\":17}"} cast_receiver.js:18
[536.994s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Buffering state changed, isPlayerBuffering: false old time: 99.691977 current time: 100.728155 cast_receiver.js:18
[536.999s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message cast_receiver.js:18
[537.002s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":3,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"PLAYING\",\"currentTime\":100.728155,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false}}],\"requestId\":0}"}
```

I've no idea what's going on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was this working before?

Comment: Yes, before it worked perfectly. Didn't use it for a month and a half, and now it don't work any more

Comment: What receiver are you using?

Comment: Styled receiver, nothing special.

Comment: I've never worked with javaScript and Styled receiver did what i needed it to :P

Comment: Can you try CastVideos-android and see if that successfully seeks?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to seek in the videos.

Comment: I would also like to point out that seeking works when I'm casting to a DLNA device (I've added support for DLNA myself). So in my opinion, it's noting wrong with the stream that's being played.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: My problem was that I was passing `position` in seconds. Changing to milliseconds fixed the problem with me. @PontusEndlessmindHolmberg your situation seems different so if you have found your answer, I'd be happy to read about it, and vote it too. ;)

Comment: I never found an answer. As the app i question was the app GMobile (aka GrooveMobile) and was using Grooveshark has a data source, the app was rendered useless when they shut down in March 2015.